# Simulate Fn+F11 key press

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, hardware, driver

Can you tell me how I can simulate key presses <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> on a laptop? Do I have to write a driver, or something like that?

The platform is Windows XP Pro SP3. Programming Language is C/C++. The purpose is create a program that allow to change enable/disable via GUI some hardware device that can turned off/on only with this hotkey. The IDE is Visual Studio 2010

Comment: `notebook` tag removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Won't work. The <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> key combo on laptops isn't handled by the OS; it's processed in Systems Management Mode - a BIOS feature, essentially.

Comment: D'oh! Can i modify the OS driver to do particulary things when is catchet the Fn+F11 key combo?

Comment: Apparently I wasn't explicit enough - the OS driver is not involved. It doesn't catch the key combo.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to simulate <kbd>F5</kbd> press to cause a refresh in a web browser:

```
INPUT inp[2]= {0};
inp[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inp[0].ki.wVk = VK_F5;
inp[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inp[1].ki.wVk = VK_F5;
inp[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(2, inp, sizeof(INPUT));
```

To simulate the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>FX</kbd> Key you might have to search for special codes.

Comment: _"To simulate the Fn + FX Key you might have to search for special codes"_ - That doesn't really answer the question, OP is specifically asking about `Fn` key in **conjunction** with other function keys such as on a laptop.