# How to press the Fn + function keys on Windows?

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

In previous scripts, I have been able to use the `SendKeys` method to press non-alphabetic keys on my computer like the following to simulate muting,
`WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))`.

However, I cannot seem to find the ability to simulate pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> and any of the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys. I am trying specifically to press the "Lower Screen Brightness" key, which is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on my keyboard.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: [Related](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/183840/How-can-I-press-both-function-key-fn-and-f-at-th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Fn` keys on a laptop are usually implemented at the hardware or driver level. See: the answer to a similar question: [How to press Fn+F11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684579/534406)

Your best bet is to find a method of performing the action directly from the OS rather than trying to press a key that doesn't 'exist' as far as Windows is concerned. In the case of screen brightness, there are other ways to do that. [This solution is written in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196953/534406) but if you really needed to do it in VBScript, you could potentially write a COM or DLL to handle it.