# C# Simulate Pressing FN key

Tags: c#

I know how to simulate a key press like a letter or f1 etc but i'm having trouble simulating the "FN" key. I've been researching it for a bit and havent found much success with actually simulating the click but rather checking for the click. If anyone can help me out that would be appreciated. Also I checked the virtual-code list for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate Fn+F11 key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684099/simulate-fnf11-key-press).  Though flagged as `c/c++` it's still relevant considering the accepted answer